# Watin tests running much slower on Teamcity

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, teamcity, watin, gui-testing

I have a set of Watin GUI tests that run on Teamcity. They each run in about 300 seconds locally. They previously ran in about the same time on a TeamCity agent (PC specs are about the same). For some reason they now run incredibly slow. The tests have a timeout of 1500 seconds and this is being triggered to cause them to fail.

I have checked the tests again locally and they run in the same time as expected (about 300 seconds). When I remote view into the Team City agent I can see that the tests are keying in text at a very slow pace. The actual speed at which tests operate is slower. It almost seems as if the tests are set to run at a quarter speed if such a thing existed.

These tests are only run about once every two weeks so its possible something on the agent has changed to effect their functionality.

I am at a loss as to what could be wrong. I've never encountered this before and on paper everything is correct but it is just going slow.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it only .TypeText that is slow? Or are you able to measure that the entire codebase is slow? I've found cases were TypeText is extremely slow in some instances and I ended up changing it to .Value (not always possible because of client validations, etc.)